# Need insight on how to build javascript fetch API

Tags: javascript, rest, api, design-patterns, refactoring

I am creating a web app with django rest framework as backend and react as frontend. The react app i generated from create-react-app. To make api call, i use fetch Api. I see some repetition in my api call that need to a reafactor. But i know which pattern is better here.

Here is the code:

Api.js

```
let _options = {headers: new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'})}

const _url = {
  'users': '/api/users/',
  'obtain-token': '/api/obtain-token/',
  'verify-token': '/api/verify-token/',
  'refresh-token': '/api/refresh-token/'
}

const _fetch = (request) => {
  return fetch(request)
    .then(res => {
      if ( ! res.ok) {
        let err = {
          'status': res.status,
          'statusText': res.statusText,
          'data': {}
        }
        return res.json().then(
          data => {
            err.data = data
            return Promise.reject(new Error(JSON.stringify(err)))
          },
          () => Promise.reject(new Error(JSON.stringify(err)))
        )
      }

      return res.json()
    })
    .catch(err => {
      return Promise.reject(err)
    })
}

export const obtainToken = (username, password) => {
  const credential = {username, password}

  let options = _options
  options.method = 'POST'
  options.body = JSON.stringify(credential)

  const request = new Request(_url['obtain-token'], options)

  return _fetch(request)
}

export const verifyToken = (token) => {
  let options = _options
  options.method = 'POST'
  options.body = JSON.stringify({token})

  const request = new Request(_url['verify-token'], options)

  return _fetch(request)
}

export const refreshToken = (token) => {
  let options = _options
  options.method = 'POST'
  options.body = JSON.stringify({token})

  const request = new Request(_url['refresh-token'], options)

  return _fetch(request)
}

export const getUser = (username, token='') => {
  let options = _options
  options.method = 'GET'
  if (token) options.headers.append('Authorization', `JWT ${token}`)

  const request = new Request(`${_url['users']}/${username}`, options)

  return _fetch(request)
}
```

What i like from this code is, when i need to request a resource, i just run a function with needed parameter without knowing it is get or post or else, and i dont need to pass header configuration and url.

```
// example api call
let token = '4346h9r7yt47t9...'

verifyToken(token)
  .then(data => {
    // server response json available here

    token = data.token
  })
  .catch(err => {
    // handle network error and bad response here

    console.log(err)
  })
```

Im follwing @challenger solution. And manage to get it shorter with this:

```
// Change _build function name to makeRequest and export it
const makeRequest = (name, _url='', body=undefined, headers={}) => {
  let [method, url] = source[name]
  let options = {
     headers: new Headers({
       'Content-Type': 'application/json',
       ...headers,
     })
   }
  options.method = method
  if (body) options.body = JSON.stringify(body)
  return _fetch(url+_url, options)
}

export default makeRequest
```

But, of course to call this function i need to supply the appended url, and a custom header if needed. But as this project goes it's proved that appended url (use by user detail resource) and costum header (use by resource that need authentication) is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let source = {
  'getUser': (..._p) => ['GET', `/api/users/${_p[0]}`, undefined, {'Authorization': `JWT ${_p[1]}`}],
  'obtainToken': (..._p) => ['POST','/api/obtain-token/', {username:_p[0], password:_p[1]}],
  'verifyToken': (..._p) => ['POST','/api/verify-token/', {token:_p[0]}],
  'refreshToken': (..._p) => ['POST', '/api/refresh-token/',{token:_p[0]}]
}


const requests = {}
Object.keys(source).forEach(key => {
  requests[key] = (...params) => {
    let [method, url, body, headers ={}] = source[key](...params)
    let options = {
       headers: new Headers({
         'Content-Type': 'application/json',
         ...headers,
       })
     }
    options.method = method
    if (body) options.body = JSON.stringify(body)
    return _fetch(new Request(url, options))
  }
})

export default requests
```

it needs more testing and review..

Comment: did you check it ?

Comment: Interesting, with previous solution the parameters send to api call is strict (it need to be in certain order), and i wonder for a while if i can do function call like python (with kwargs, ex: makeRequest(name='users')). But this solution answer it in some ways i think.

One think thought, my users resource doesn't have to had authorization header. In the backend, users endpoint will response with different data if token exist.

Comment: I missed some things... I think I fixed them now... if you checked it please inform me

Comment: did you consider using axios ? https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios it's great and simple...

Comment: i move authorization headers to Objects.keys function, it will add authorization header if token supplied to a requests function.

Comment: I'll stick with fetch, as right now my code still readable to me.

Answer (score 2):

```
let source = {
  'getUser': ['GET', '/api/users/'],
  'obtain-token': ['POST','/api/obtain-token/'],
  'verify-token': ['POST','/api/verify-token/'],
  'refresh-token':['POST', '/api/refresh-token/']
}

let _build = (name, _url, body, headers) => {
  let [method, url] = source[name]
  let options = {
     headers: new Headers({
       'Content-Type': 'application/json',
       ...headers,
     })
   }
  options.method = method
  if (body) options.body = JSON.stringify(body)
  return new Request(url+_url, options)
}
```

and then

```
export const obtainToken = (username, password) => {
  const credential = {username, password}
  const request = _build('obtainToken','', credential, {})
  return _fetch(request)
}
export const verifyToken = (token) => {
  const request = _build('verifyToken', '',{token}, {})
  return _fetch(request)
}

export const refreshToken = (token) => {
  const request = _build('refreshToken', '', {token}, {})
  return _fetch(request)
}
export const getUser = (username, token='') => {
  let headers = {'Authorization': `JWT ${token}`}

  const request = _build('getUser',`/${username}`, undefined, headers)
  return _fetch(request)
}
```

even more, instead of...

```
return new Request(url+_url, options)
```

in the _build function you can replace it with

```
return _fetch(new Request(url+_url, options))
```

which allows you to have this:

```
   export const obtainToken = (username, password) => {
      const credential = {username, password}
      return _build('obtainToken','', credential, {})
    }
    export const verifyToken = (token) => {
      return _build('verifyToken', '',{token}, {})
    }

    export const refreshToken = (token) => {
      retun _build('refreshToken', '', {token}, {})
    }

    export const getUser = (username, token='') => {
      let headers = {'Authorization': `JWT ${token}`}
      return _build('getUser',`/${username}`, undefined, headers)
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, this is really what i want.

Comment: you are welcome, you can even do more by using export default {...and here you use the build function that will build directly from the source } and it's more complicated...

Comment: I updated my question using your solution right now and manage to cut it shorter.